# Group Cassandra entries by nearby timestamp

Tags: apache-spark, cassandra, apache-storm

I have this Cassandra table:

```
CREATE TABLE events(
    userId uuid,
    datetime timestamp,
    id uuid,
    event text,
    PRIMARY KEY (userId, datetime, id)
);
```

What I want to do is group events that happened around the same time for a specific user. So, for example, if events for one user happen at:

```
9:00:11 AM
9:00:13 AM
9:00:16 AM

9:03:55 AM
9:03:58 AM
9:04:03 AM

9:15:35 AM
9:15:38 AM
```

I would want to get 3 groups:

```
1: 9:00:11 AM to 9:00:16 AM
2: 9:03:55 AM to 9:04:03 AM
3: 9:15:35 AM to 9:15:38 AM
```

I hope a machine learning algorithm such as 
[DBSCAN](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBSCAN) can figure out how the clustering should be done, but grouping events that have an interval of less than a minute between them would probably be enough.

Bonus points if I can get a confidence interval on the start and end time of each groups.

I've looked into using basic CQL like `group by`, Apache Spark's `groupByKey` and MLib Clustering without any success. Ideally, results would be processed in near real-time with Apache Spark Streaming.

This is a greenfield project, so Cassandra and Spark are not a must. I've also considered using Storm.

Comment: _around the same time_ is not a good specification and definitely not something we can convert to code. For starters is there a limit of a size of the window? If so what happens with groups overlap. Or maybe it is just a difference between consecutive events?

Comment: You are right, this is not a clear specification. I was hoping a machine learning algorithm could figure out how the clustering should be done. However, grouping events that have an interval of less than a minute between them would probably be enough. Thanks for the feedback.

Comment: If you change the schema, you can create arbitrary buckets as a clustering key (before/left of the timestamp), and use that for grouping.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems you are talking about *session windows*. Right now I am only aware of Google Dataflow to give you system support for this. If you use Storm, you would need to hand code the sessioning logic.

In any case, if you are using a streaming system, you first need to sort your data on timestamps and stream them in ascending timestamp order through the system.

Apache Flink might give you some more support than Storm to code this, but it would be a manual effort, too. Even if Flink is closer to Google Dataflow than Storm (Flink might also add session windows in the near future).

Btw: the `groupBy` / `keyBy` statements you mentioned would be appropriate to partition the data by user-id, but not for building windows.

Comment: Yes, Session Windowing is what I'm trying to do. Good to have a term for it! [Google Dataflow](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/model/windowing#fig6) seems great, but an open source alternative would be better. It's hard to find as you've mentioned. Thanks!

Comment: In the open source space, Apache Flink should give you the best start to do session windows I guess.

Comment: Dataflow engineer here. Please note that Dataflow also does *not* have the requirement that data be pre-sorted on timestamps - its semantics is mainly defined on event time (when the event happened), not processing time (when it was processed), in order to support realistic out-of-order streams, backfilling etc. I believe Flink is either rapidly working to support Dataflow's windowing semantics, or has just recently implemented it - so if you're looking at an open-source alternative, that's where you should look. Spark streaming and Storm are much farther away from providing similar semantics.